# ignore spaces while comparing tokens files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a script in which there is two file. I have to compare both file and have to display the content of mismatching file, e.g.:

```
file1
file2
```

content of file1:

```
abcd
efgh
ijk
```

content of file2:

```
abcd=123
efgh=
ijkl=1213
```

1. if the matching don't occur, it should display like matching not occur.
2. if the matching name occur but the value of respective name is not present in file2. It should display like the value is missing.

e.g. `aefgh` is present in bothy file but the value of `efgh` is not present in file 2.so it should display the matching value is not present.

```
 file="$HOME/SAMPLE/token_values.txt"
 while read -r var
 do
 if grep "$var" environ.ref >/dev/null
 then
 :
 else
 print "$var ((((((Not Present))))))" >> final13.txt
 fi
 done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this script would do it :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #below line removes the blank lines in the first file
 fileprocessed1=$( sed '/^$/d' your_file1 )
 #below line removes the blank lines and replaces the = with blank space in the second file
 fileprocessed2=$( sed '{/^$/d};{s/=/\ /g}' your_file2 )

 paste  <(echo "$fileprocessed1") <(echo "$fileprocessed2")| awk '{
 if($1 == $2)
   {
     if(length($3) == 0)
        {
        print NR" : Match found but value Missing for "$2
        }
     else
        {
        print NR" : Match found for "$1" with value "$3
        }
   }
 else
   {
    print NR" : No match for "$1
   }
 }'
```

would give :

```
1 : Match found for bcd with value 123
2 : Match found but value missing for efgh
3 : No match for ijk
```

for the files you have given.

But I really hope somebody would come with a one-liner for this one. :)

Comment: thanks..but its not fetching the name and value that which token are missing and which one matched.

Comment: @edit You have the line number at the left where the value is missing ;) Please ee my edit - I have added name-value pairs.

Comment: actully..its not comparing the actual file..what i need is to comapre both the file line by line if not present or missing then print it accordingly..by this script its getting all the file name to unpresnt it takes the blank spaces in file 2 . but it should take the space after = if the token name matched but value is unmatched.

Comment: it gives the blank spaces in file2 but i want to print the spaces after compare of both file and if the value of token is not there in other file it shold reflect.

Comment: if there is spaces in second file to which we are comaparing first file then we are getting printes the spaces in second file not the spaces of the tojen name which value are not present.

Comment: @UttamShukla : Sorry pal ! I am not able to understand what you're saying. You never mentioned about spaces in your question so my answer was tailor made for what you have posted. Regarding `if there is spaces in second file ` - what spaces do you mean? Blank lines?

Comment: And the blank lines only in the second file? What about the first file?

Comment: I have improvised my answer a bit to deal with blank spaces in both files. Please see the edit.. The actual files are not changed only a copy is made. @UttamShukla

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle it something like this in `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $file1, '<', "~/SAMPLE/token_values.txt" ) or die $!; 
chomp ( my @tokens = <$file1> ); 

open ( my $file2, '<', 'environ.ref' ) or die $!; 
my %data = map { /(\w+)=(\w*)/ } <$file2>; 

for my $thing ( @tokens ) {
    print $thing,"\n" unless $data{$thing} eq '';
}
```